# send html page data to python flask variable

Tags: python, html, flask

I know this question has been asked many time but those answers are not helping me, pardon me for asking again.

I am taking data in form at index.html page and presenting in next html page (annodisplay.html) for user to review and before he click submit. 
I am looking to pass the data to python variables only once user  press the submit button. But I am not getting the form values in python variables.

Here is my python flask code.

```
app = Flask(__name__) 
@app.route('/send', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def send():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        affflash = request.form['affflash']
        return render_template('annodisplay.html', affflash=affflash)
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/get', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template('submit.html')
    return render_template('annodisplay.html')  
    affflash = request.form['affflash']
    print affflash 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my HTML index.html code

```
<form method="POST" action="/send">
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">AFF_FLASH</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">
    <select id="AFF_FLASH" name="affflash">
        <option selected value="">Select</option>
        <option value="Yes">YES</option>
        <option value="No">NO</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>                
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">    
            </form>
```

Here is my annodisplay.html code

```
<form action="{{ url_for('get') }}" method="POST">
        <body>
            <table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-bh7e">AFF Flash</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">{{ affflash }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </body>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you run that Flask app at all?. Since I cannot see any root route like `@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index(): ` how can I get to that **index.html** ?

Comment: Yes, I can. Funtion send has return reponse for index.html. return render_template('index.html')"

Answer (score 0):

we use the `request.form.get()` function on form submit via POST (I guess in your case `get` is missing)
And normally we use regular brackets. I am not sure if the interpreter will be fine with your squared brackets. 
I hope that helps you

Comment: Ok, so with both request.form.get() & request.values.get() it is working but I am getting None as value. `affflash = request.form.get('affflash')print affflash` output is `127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2018 19:48:13] "POST /send HTTP/1.1" 200 -
None
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2018 19:48:18] "POST /get HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: Nice. if you are using Python 3.x, print content must be in brackets: `print (affflash)` and may be you should always choose something from dropdown to print the value,your default `value` is empty!.